# Getting the width and height of the Activity not the physical screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity

After googling on getting the width and height of the screen I have encountered the code below but this seems to get the physical width and height which makes a Rectangles that i am generating out of bounds.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

I also tried the code below but I am still faced with the same issue, I believe that these aren't the proper ways to get the width and height of the activity. Could anyone provide methods on how to accomplish this (Getting the width and height of the Activity a user is currently in)

```
int width = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels - con;
int height = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - con1;
```

Comment: You can calculate it from your views in the activity!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize(android.graphics.Point)).

```
Point screenSize = new Point();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(screenSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It worked for me.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;

you need to pass context if you are using it outside activity.
Replace "this" with your context.
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need width and height of your Activity's decor view.

```
int width = getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
int height = getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
```